# Register only implementations of a interface to a Spring Application Context?

Tags: spring

I have a set of classes as follows.

```
public class ServiceA implements CommonInterface
{
   public void startA()
   {
       ....
   }
}

public class ServiceB implements CommonInterface
{
   public void startB()
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

Is there any way in Spring-framework to auto-register only the classes which implement a CommonInterface to a application context and access them?

Comment: Why not to use `@Service` annotation to any implementation? And why not to use `@Autowire` with implementation's type to access?

Comment: @KenBekov :  `@Service` will enable register by scanning base-packages.But I need more filters like - the class types which implement CommonInterface.`@Autowire` on the other hand, will only help the to auto-inject referenced objects,which is not my scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its possible. If you are using Java Configuration you can filter components to those that implement a specific interface using @ComponetScan. You need to disable the default filters used by Spring (based on detecting stereotype annotated classes i.e @Component , @Service etc).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mydomain.myapp.service"} , useDefaultFilters = false , includeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE , value = CommonInterface.class)})
public class AppConfig{
   //@Bean methods
}
```

The same can also be achieved in xml using context:component-scan

Comment: Yes. That looks good. I don't have a @Configuration class to register the services though. Is the same filter applicable for applicationcontext's scan api as well. Let me check.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.myapp.service" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="com.mydomain.myapp.service.CommonInterface" />
</context:component-scan>

Comment: Sorry I'll rephrase. I dont have a beans.xml file nor a `@configuration` class. All I want to do is instantiate a `annotationConfigApplicationContext` object and use it's `scan` api to provide filters. Function of `scan` is similar to `componentscan` but it is via `applicationcontext` object and not a `config` object.

Comment: It's ok. I dont mind creating a config class. But `value = CommonInterface` is throwing a compiler error - Syntax error on token '='. Browsed, but unable to figure out.

Comment: That's perfect.Thanks